# Any software that allows me to create documents and maps with links to other documents or photos?

Tags: software, world-building

I have to create a small world for my WIP game so I can submit it as my thesis. While I am aware I can use simple text editors (my usual choice) I want to be able to create a tree/web of my ideas, connecting them without having to look through many documents.

A more specific example is

My hero's description > there's a country mentioned there, click it > the country's description > there's an animal mentioned there, click it > see a drawing of said animal.

Answer (score 4):

I am going to refer you to a question on WorldBuilding.SE: [What software is available for keeping and organising notes about your world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/499/28789), specifically the [accepted answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/502/28789):

> It sounds like what you really want is an private wiki. You apparently weren't able to find one though, apparently they are pretty common.
>
> The biggest one is [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) (the power behind Wikipedia). MediaWiki can be private, and it's not too hard. See this [tutorial](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Simple_private_wiki) for information on how to do that. But basically you would create one account and limit it to that. As a bonus MediaWiki is open source and free.
>
> Another option would be [DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org) on a Stick. This would be a simple home wiki that you could transport around on a USB drive, or possible share over the internet. To see set up look [here](https://www.dokuwiki.org/install:dokuwiki_on_a_stick). And it can still be private. DokuWiki is also open source and free!

Using a wiki, similar to Wikipedia, would allow you to do what you are looking for: jumping from one point to another via Hyperlinks. Just like when you find something interesting on Wikipedia you will be able to quickly click on a link of your heroe's name, the city that he visits in your description of chapter x, pictures of items, ...

Other than that you would have the formatting capabilities of Wikipedia and you would be able to easily share your document with other people you are working with, which makes it easier to collaborate on a bigger project. Even if you are not planning to work with a lot of other people, you might at one point give someone the opportunity to look through your notes. Maybe it's just a friend that's interested in what you are doing, or it's someone who wants to work with you on a future project. You might also be able to submit this together with your thesis.

Please note that I have not used the software that is decribed above myself. I merely cited the WorldBuilding answer from [DonyorM](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/81/donyorm). If this helped you please check out the linked question/answer on WB.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Word has the ability [to add hyperlinks to any bookmark or heading within the current document](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-edit-a-hyperlink-5D8C0804-F998-4143-86B1-1199735E07BF).  The process basically works the same as adding web-based hyperlinks.

1. Select the text or image which will become the link and then right-click to bring up the popup menu.
2. Select the Hyperlink menu option.
3. In the resulting "Insert Hyperlink" dialog, select "Place In This Document" and when a list of existing Headings and Bookmarks appear, choose where you want the link to go.
4. You can also add a Screen Tip (the text which appears during mouseover) using the "Screen Tip" button on this same dialog box.
5. Press the "OK " button when you are done and the hyperlink will be created.

To Create Destinations for your in-document hyperlinks...

- **Headings** - any text within the document which has either the "Headings 1" or "Headings 2" style applied to it will appear in the "Place In This Document" list of the "Insert Hyperlink" Dialog box.
- **BookMarks** - select any block of text and then click the "BookMarks" button from the "Insert" tab-bar and when the "BookMarks" dialog box appears, enter a short name for your bookmark and press the Add button.  This will make the selected text into a bookmark which will appear in the "Place In This Document" list of the "Insert Hyperlink" Dialog box.

As for adding hyperlinks to maps, I know that you can select an entire image from within your document to become the hyperlink.  It appears that you can also create what is called an ["Image Map"](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/create-image-map-microsoft-word-powerpoint-75286.html) in which multiple transparent shapes float above your image within the document, and each of those shapes can be a hyperlink with a separate destination and screen tip.  I have no experience using image maps within Word.

Answer (score 1):

[CherryTree](https://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/) has

- internal links,
- tree of documents with drag-and-drop,
- table of contents generation,
- embedded images,
- links to images.

It's a desktop program and you you can keep your ideas in one zipped password-protected file on a USB-stick.

I would say you can use it as a personal desktop Wiki or CMS. It has search, bookmarks, rich text editing and many small features you didn't know you want to use (like backups eg.)